# Shogun - Missing Java Package

Tags: java, machine-learning, package, shogun

I'm currently trying to use the Shogun toolbox (on Mac OS). I've just installed the corresponding homebrew-core-Shogun library, I didn't get any error so everything should be fine here.

As I'm creating a Java project to use interfaces I've followed the instructions and started my Java class including 2 Java packages import: `import org.shogun.*;` and `import org.jblas.*;`.

I had to download the jblas package from another website as mentioned in the Shogun instructions, however I can't figure out where the shogun package is.
I probably missed something but can't figure out which step I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

I answered my own question. I deleted the "build" repository that had to be created and recompiled again there Shogun source code.
Just in case it may help somebody I ran cmake with the following options: cmake -DLICENSE_GPL_SHOGUN=OFF -DUSE_SVMLIGHT=OFF -DBUILD_META_EXAMPLES=OFF  ..

And digging into the usr/local/cellar/shogun/6.1.3/share/java I finally found my shogun.jar